# python docx changes apostrophe to €™

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-docx

I created a simple delMe.docx file in MSWord v2002 with

> If numbers aren’t beautiful, I don’t know what is. –Paul Erdős

Run the simple program:

```
import docx
hDoc = docx.Document('delMe.docx')
hDoc.save('delMe2.docx')
```

and do a beyondcompare2 that shows delMe2 as

> If numbers arenâ€™t beautiful, I donâ€™t know what is. â€“PaulÂ ErdÅ‘s

and delMe as

> If numbers aren’t beautiful, I don’t know what is. –Paul Erdős

I played with BC2 settings and poked at docx documentation but couldn't find anything that suggested I could/need to change the encoding or the save.  What is that simple little thing I'm not doing?
Thanks,
-Chris

Comment: [See this](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-to-get-from-theyre-to-theyre/). A quick Google search is worth it.

Comment: Python and docx version?  Looks like docx read the data and assumed `Windows-1252` encoding instead of `UTF-8`.  Or maybe it read it correctly, but wrote it (possibly correctly) as UTF-8, but BC2 is assuming Windows-1252 for display.  Did you try to load delMe2.docx in Word again? Word2002 is pretty old and maybe saved in Windows-1252.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I did a little research on encoding but was hoping not to have to become an expert.  I know selfish.

Comment: Python 3.8.3, python-docx 0.8.10.  delMe2.docx opens and appears fine in Word2002.  In BC2, the doc type/encoding shows as MS Word Documents/Converted/ Unicode/ BOM PC.  When I select the encoding drop down, 'Don't Override' is selected.  Selecting other encodings (ansi, utf-8, etc) does not appropriately display the text.  Also, I'm using BC3, not BC2.